# Query for array elements inside Jsonb type postgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql-10

I have a psql table where one of the jsonb data is extracted over it.

```json
{
  "SrcRcs": [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 158], 
  "reason": "", 
  "result": "Success", 
  "InitTech": 1
}
```

This column is named `Data` and is of type `jsonb`.

I am extracting the `SrcRcs` data from the jsonb:

```
select Data->'SrcRcs' from table_name;
```

Output:

```
[4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 158]
```

But which is in unsorted order as from the jsonb.

I want it in the sorted order like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,158]
```

Can someone please help me out?

I have tried the psql sort() but wasn't able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the array elements and then aggregate them back in a sorted way:

```
SELECT (select jsonb_agg(i::int order by i::int)
        from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'SrcRcs') as t(i)) 
from the_table
```

If you want, you can create a function for this to make the SQL queries easier.